# R Shiny renderPlotly with multiple conditions

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny

I am making a Shiny app that allows the user to:

1. Upload a CSV file
2. Output summary
3. Select columns/variables to plot

Based on the `input y` selected column I want the app to filter the data. For example, let's the say the user selects the column/variable `tmean`. Now, the data has a `variable` column which has `tmean`, `TMax` and `TMin` corresponding to the `tmean`, `TMax` and `TMin` values. So, the app will then filter just the `tmean` data by setting `filter` in `variable` column to `tmean.

Since, I have three temperature variables, I tried using conditional statements for filtering the data. However, the conditional statements are returning an error:

```
Warning in if (.) input$y == "tmean" else { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
Warning: Error in if: argument is not interpretable as logical
```

How can I fix this?

Sample Data:

```
structure(list(tmean = c(19.02, 15.14, 20.17, 20.37, 24.7, 26.03, 
28.19, 28.89, 28.36, 27.71, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), TMax = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 28.07, 28.53, 28.92, 28.22, 26.91, 28.83, 28.13, 25.33, 
24.05, 29.98, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), TMin = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 21.75, 
21.76, 19.97, 19.48, 21.31, 21.76, 21.55, 21.54, 21.72, 21.49
), year = c(1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1981L, 1981L, 
1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1981L, 
1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1981L, 
1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L), month = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), variable = c("tmean", 
"tmean", "tmean", "tmean", "tmean", "tmean", "tmean", "tmean", 
"tmean", "tmean", "TMax", "TMax", "TMax", "TMax", "TMax", "TMax", 
"TMax", "TMax", "TMax", "TMax", "TMin", "TMin", "TMin", "TMin", 
"TMin", "TMin", "TMin", "TMin", "TMin", "TMin")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-30L))
```

[Here](https://app.box.com/s/geicxuloenhbksprdjd4aj2o8g5ua6xe) is the complete data for further reference

Desired output (Based on the original data):

[image]

Selection Criteria (`y-axis variable can also be TMax or TMin`):

[image]

Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
# Define UI for application that draws an interactive ggplot
options(shiny.maxRequestSize=1024*1024^2)
ui =   navbarPage("Data",
                  tabPanel("Uploading Files",
                           sidebarLayout(
                             sidebarPanel(
                               radioButtons(
                                 "File_Type",
                                 label = "Choose File type",
                                 choices = list(".csv/txt" = 1, ".xlsx" = 2),
                                 selected = 1,
                                 inline = TRUE
                               ),
                               
                               fileInput('file2', 'Upload Your Data',
                                         accept = c(
                                           'text/csv',
                                           'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain',
                                           '.csv',
                                           '.xlsx'
                                         ))),
                             mainPanel(
                               verbatimTextOutput("summary")
                             )
                             
                           )),
                  
                  tabPanel("Data Plots",
                           sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(
                             selectInput("x", label = "Select x-axis Variable:",
                                         choices = NULL),
                             selectInput("y", label = "Select y-axis Variable: ",
                                         choices = NULL),
                             selectInput("color", label =  "Select Grouping variable (optional): ",
                                         choices = NULL)),
                             mainPanel(
                               plotlyOutput("TSM")
                             )))
)


# Tell the server how to assemble inputs into outputs
server = function(input, output, session) {
  # Code for uploading an MS-Excel file for plotting
  # Get the uploaded file
  myData = reactive({
    req(input$file2)
    inFile = input$file2
    if (is.null(inFile)) return(NULL)
    data = read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE)
    data
  })
  
  observe({
    data = req(myData())
    updateSelectInput(session, 'x', choices = names(data), select=names(data)[2])
    updateSelectInput(session, 'y', choices = names(data), select=names(data)[1])
    updateSelectInput(session, 'color', choices = names(data), select=names(data)[3])
  })
  
  output$summary = renderPrint({
    summary(myData())
  })

    df2 = reactive({
    req(myData(),input$x, input$y, input$color)
    myData() %>%
      if (input$y == "tmean") {
        myData() %>%
          filter(variable == "tmean") }

    else if (input$y == "TMin") {
      myData() %>%
        filter(variable == "TMin") }

    else if (input$y == "TMax") {
      myData() %>%
        filter(variable == "TMax") } %>%            
        group_by(.data[[input$x]], .data[[input$y]]) %>%
        dplyr::summarise(AvgTemp = mean(.data[[input$y]]))
  })
  
  #TSM
  output$TSM =  renderPlotly({
    req(df2(), input$x, input$y, input$color)

    df2() %>%
     ggplot(aes(x = .data[[input$x]], y = AvgTemp, color = as.factor(.data[[input$color]]))) +
     labs(color = "Legend") +
     geom_line() +
     ggtitle("Timeseries Plot By Month")

  })
  
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I think you need mutate instead of summarize as in `dplyr::mutate(AvgTemp = mean(.data[[input$y]]))`?

Comment: Yes, that's what's I did based on the answer but then it returns this error `Column name year must not be duplicated. Use .name_repair to specify repair. Caused by error in stop_vctrs(): ! Names must be unique. x These names are duplicated:   * "year" at locations 1 and 3.   110: <Anonymous>` when I select the `year` column as the `x-axis variable`.

Comment: That is because your sample has `variable` and your real data has `Variable` as the name.  Also, the order of variables are different. Please try the updated code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
# Define UI for application that draws an interactive ggplot
options(shiny.maxRequestSize=1024*1024^2)
ui =   navbarPage("Data",
                  tabPanel("Uploading Files",
                           sidebarLayout(
                             sidebarPanel(
                               radioButtons(
                                 "File_Type",
                                 label = "Choose File type",
                                 choices = list(".csv/txt" = 1, ".xlsx" = 2),
                                 selected = 1,
                                 inline = TRUE
                               ),
                               
                               fileInput('file2', 'Upload Your Data',
                                         accept = c(
                                           'text/csv',
                                           'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain',
                                           '.csv',
                                           '.xlsx'
                                         ))),
                             mainPanel(
                               verbatimTextOutput("summary")
                             )
                             
                           )),
                  
                  tabPanel("Data Plots",
                           sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(
                             selectInput("x", label = "Select x-axis Variable:",
                                         choices = NULL),
                             selectInput("y", label = "Select y-axis Variable: ",
                                         choices = NULL),
                             selectInput("color", label =  "Select Grouping variable (optional): ",
                                         choices = NULL)),
                             mainPanel(
                               plotlyOutput("TSM", height = 500)
                             )))
)


# Tell the server how to assemble inputs into outputs
server = function(input, output, session) {
  # Code for uploading an MS-Excel file for plotting
  # Get the uploaded file
  myData = reactive({
    req(input$file2)
    inFile = input$file2
    if (is.null(inFile)) return(NULL)
    data = read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE)
    data
  })
  
  observe({
    data = req(myData())
    updateSelectInput(session, 'x', choices = names(data), select=names(data)[3])
    updateSelectInput(session, 'y', choices = names(data), select=names(data)[1])
    updateSelectInput(session, 'color', choices = names(data), select=names(data)[4])
  })
  
  output$summary = renderPrint({
    req(myData())
    summary(myData())
  })
  
  df2 = reactive({
    req(myData(),input$x, input$y)
    myData() %>% dplyr::filter(Variable %in% input$y)  %>%   
      group_by(.data[[input$x]], .data[[input$y]], .data[[input$color]]) %>%
      dplyr::mutate(AvgTemp = mean(.data[[input$y]]))
  })
  observe({print(df2())})
  #TSM
  output$TSM =  renderPlotly({
    req(df2(), input$x, input$y, input$color)
    
    df2() %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = .data[[input$x]], y = AvgTemp, color = as.factor(.data[[input$color]]) )) + 
      labs(color = "Legend") +
      geom_line() +
      ggtitle("Timeseries Plot By Month")
    
  })
  
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: output]

Comment: You removed color, but I want to have separate lines for each `month` (as shown in example desired output)which is `input$color` in this case. Secondly, the plot is not picking up `AvgTemp`. And I am summarizing the selected `temperature` column to `AvgTemp` because it's spatial data and so each month has multiple values.

Comment: so do I need to do ` df2 = reactive({ req(myData(),input$x, input$y, input$color)  ...` ?

Comment: I am  getting this error from `observe({print(df2())})` `Error in <Anonymous>: error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'print': `

Comment: Thank you, almost there, however `AvgTemp` is not getting plotted on the `y-axis`. It does plot the `y-axis` variable based on the `input` selection but not `AvgTemp`.

Comment: in `df2()` I tried changing `dplyr::summarise(AvgTemp = mean(.data[[input$y]]))` to `summarize(AvgTemp = mean(.data[[input$y]]))`, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: so `variable` column is there sort of like a `key` so you will notice, for example, in the sample data whenever the value in the `tmean` column is > `0` then corresponding rows in `variable` column are `tmean`. This way I can filter the data if have data by `tmean` , `TMax` or `TMin` based on the variable column.

Comment: I am getting this error now `Column name year must not be duplicated.
Use .name_repair to specify repair.
Caused by error in `stop_vctrs()`:
! Names must be unique.
x These names are duplicated:
  * "year" at locations 1 and 3.
  110: <Anonymous>` when I select the `year` column as the `x-axis` variable.

Comment: Another update: the new `AvgTemp` column is also not showing in the `input select menus`.

Comment: Also the new `AvgTemp` column (based on the original data) is not as intended based on the above code as the number of rows are `29,322`. However, I was after something like this `df = df %>% filter(Variable == "tmean") %>% group_by(year, month)  %>% summarize(AvgTemp = mean(tmean))` which returns `504` rows for `AvgTemp`.